# Angular app deployed to Heroku fails to launch

Tags: node.js, git, angular, heroku, deployment

I'm attempting to deploy an Angular App to Heroku using Git. The app is fully functional when using the Angular CLI and viewing at `localhost`. I have a small Node.js server for serving the static files.

My Heroku deployment gets tagged as built with no errors, but upon trying to connect, it fails.

**The Heroku logs:**

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ../server.js`
[web.1]: module.js:471
app[web.1]:     throw err;
app[web.1]:     ^
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/server.js'
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I see that it cannot find `server.js`, but it definitely in my root directory and tracked/pushed with git:

```
>git ls-files

Procfile
dist/...
...
package.json
protractor.conf.js
server.js
src/app/app.component.css
src/app/app.component.html
src/app/app.component.ts
src/app/app.module.ts
src/app/tenant.ts
...
```

**Procfile**:

```
web: node ../server.js
```

**server.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**package.json**, where I've set `private` to `false`:

```
{
  "name": "utilites",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node ../server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    ...
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    ...
  },
...
}
```

/dist was generated with `ng build --aot -prod`.

Any thoughts? Let me know if I've neglected to provide anything necessary to debug this deployment. Thank you for your time.

#### Solution

The issue was simple: '../server.js' should have simply been server.js in package.json & the procfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ../server.js`
```

Means that if you're running the process in `/your/path/to/server.js` , it will attempt to run `/your/path/server.js` , which doesn't exist.

Get your path straight!

Comment: Oh my. Sometimes I need someone to point out the obvious. Thanks, [I'm live now.](https://utilities-balancer.herokuapp.com/)